# cURL and PHP post request

Tags: php, curl

I am new at cURL and can`t understand. I have for example this code

```
curl -d '
{
  "data": {
    "title": "Bubble Nebula",
    "body": "It`s found today at 21:00",
    "icon": "https://peter-gribanov.github.io/serviceworker/Bubble-Nebula.jpg",
    "image": "https://peter-gribanov.github.io/serviceworker/Bubble-Nebula_big.jpg",
    "click_action": "https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/hubble-sees-a-star-inflating-a-giant-bubble"
  }
  "to": "YOUR-TOKEN-ID"
}' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: key=AAAAaGQ_q2M:APA91bGCEOduj8HM6gP24w2LEnesqM2zkL_qx2PJUSBjjeGSdJhCrDoJf_WbT7wpQZrynHlESAoZ1VHX9Nro6W_tqpJ3Aw-A292SVe_4Ho7tJQCQxSezDCoJsnqXjoaouMYIwr34vZTs" \
    -X POST "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

How should i do it work well with php?

Comment: check curl lib for php https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I just use `file_get_contents()` for my requests, but that trick is sadly only for GET requests.

However, I recently discovered a new trick that can be used with Post and Get requests(Including everything else that curl can) and still avoids the horrible php library phpcURL, And the best part is, that you don't even need to change your curl command. Try the code below.

```
<?php

$curl = "your curl command" // paste your curl command here

exec("$curl > curloutput.txt");
$response = file_get_contents("curloutput.txt");

echo($response);

?>
```

This code should execute your given curl command and return the output. Yes, I know this sounds like a really janky method but it works every time bugless and it is super easy to use.